# Construct in-memory IR CFG of C/C++ program using LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I am interested in analyzing a CFG of a C/C++ program where the CFG's nodes contain LLVM IR instructions. Is there any way to leverage LLVM to extract a persistent in-memory object of this CFG? I do not want to implement a pass in the compiler; I want the CFG to undergo analysis in my own program.

Comment: LLVM IR is already a CFG, naturally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LLVM IR in-memory representation is amenable to CFG analysis because all the basic blocks are organized as a graph already. Within a basic block, the instruction sequence is linear. Some interesting in-function CFG-related code in LLVM is: `lib/Analysis/CFG.cpp` and `lib/Analysis/CFGPrinter.cpp`